# Error from UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a Swift app that allows the user to control two `UIDatePicker` objects in the same `UIViewController`.

Unfortunately, I receive the error:

`Assertion failure in -[UIPickerTableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:]`

I am also informed that I have an `NSInternalConsistencyException` because the `UITableView` data source is not set.

I do not have any table views, just the `UIDatePicker` objects. The objects are just showing time and were added with IB. The relevant class code is:

```
class AdminHoursController: UIViewController, NSCoding, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var openHourPicker: UIDatePicker?
    @IBOutlet var closeHourPicker: UIDatePicker?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.openHourPicker!.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time
    self.closeHourPicker!.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time
    self.openHourPicker!.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    self.closeHourPicker!.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()

    self.view.addSubview(openHourPicker!)
    self.view.addSubview(closeHourPicker!)
    }
}
```